# char to double conversion

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using visual studio 15, and it generates an error when compiling code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a = 1;
    double i{ a };
    cout << i;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

> error C2397: conversion from 'char' to 'double' requires a narrowing conversion

I can not understand why, because in this conversion I think there is no narrowing.

Comment: I am not sure but is this a valid `c++` tag or it should be removed?

Comment: @FirstStep: Why? This is C++.

Comment: Did you try the same using a `static_cast<double>(a)`?

Comment: I'm a little surprised it's an *error* and not a *warning*. `gcc` reports it as a warning.

Comment: @lurker According to the standard the program is ill-formed. An error is better than a warning for this. With a warning the compiler has to go ahead anyway and guess what the programmer meant (maybe just do the cast with narrowing as defined in other parts of the standard?), and what code to generate to detect or recover if the conversion is out of bounds.

Comment: @MikeVine that makes sense. I was more struck by the inconsistency in `gcc`, and `gcc` is what I'm used to using.